# bitparallel weighted Levenshtein distance

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, levenshtein-distance

I am using a weighted Levenshtein distance with the following costs:

- insertion: 1
- deletion: 1
- replacement: 2

As pointed out by wildwasser in a comment, this means, that a substitution is treated as an insertion and a deletion. So substitutions could be avoided by the algorithm.

For the normal implementation with a cost of 1 for each operation there are multiple bitparallel implementations like e.g. Myers/Hyyrö:

```cpp
static const uint64_t masks[64] = {
    0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000003, 0x0000000000000007, 0x000000000000000f,
    0x000000000000001f, 0x000000000000003f, 0x000000000000007f, 0x00000000000000ff,
    0x00000000000001ff, 0x00000000000003ff, 0x00000000000007ff, 0x0000000000000fff,
    0x0000000000001fff, 0x0000000000003fff, 0x0000000000007fff, 0x000000000000ffff,
    0x000000000001ffff, 0x000000000003ffff, 0x000000000007ffff, 0x00000000000fffff,
    0x00000000001fffff, 0x00000000003fffff, 0x00000000007fffff, 0x0000000000ffffff,
    0x0000000001ffffff, 0x0000000003ffffff, 0x0000000007ffffff, 0x000000000fffffff,
    0x000000001fffffff, 0x000000003fffffff, 0x000000007fffffff, 0x00000000ffffffff,
    0x00000001ffffffff, 0x00000003ffffffff, 0x00000007ffffffff, 0x0000000fffffffff,
    0x0000001fffffffff, 0x0000003fffffffff, 0x0000007fffffffff, 0x000000ffffffffff,
    0x000001ffffffffff, 0x000003ffffffffff, 0x000007ffffffffff, 0x00000fffffffffff,
    0x00001fffffffffff, 0x00003fffffffffff, 0x00007fffffffffff, 0x0000ffffffffffff,
    0x0001ffffffffffff, 0x0003ffffffffffff, 0x0007ffffffffffff, 0x000fffffffffffff,
    0x001fffffffffffff, 0x003fffffffffffff, 0x007fffffffffffff, 0x00ffffffffffffff,
    0x01ffffffffffffff, 0x03ffffffffffffff, 0x07ffffffffffffff, 0x0fffffffffffffff,
    0x1fffffffffffffff, 0x3fffffffffffffff, 0x7fffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff,
};

int distance(char* a, int len_a, char* b, int len_b) {
    if (len_a > 64) {
      return -1;
    }

    uint64_t posbits[256] = {0};

    for (int i=0; i < len_a; i++){
        posbits[(unsigned char)a[i]] |= 1ull << i;
    }  
    
    int dist = len_a;
    uint64_t mask = 1ull << (len_a - 1);
    uint64_t VP   = masks[len_a - 1];
    uint64_t VN   = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < len_b; i++){
      uint64_t y = posbits[(unsigned char)b[i]];
      uint64_t X  = y | VN; 
      uint64_t D0 = ((VP + (X & VP)) ^ VP) | X;
      uint64_t HN = VP & D0;
      uint64_t HP = VN | ~(VP|D0);
      X  = (HP << 1) | 1;
      VN =  X & D0;
      VP = (HN << 1) | ~(X | D0);
      if (HP & mask) { dist++; }
      if (HN & mask) { dist--; }
    }
    return dist; 
}
```

Is there a similar algorithm to calculate this weighted version of the levenshtein distance?

Comment: Aside: `posbits[(unsigned int)a[i]]` is problematic code when `a[i] < 0`.  Recommend `posbits[(unsigned char)a[i]]`.  Minor `ll` not needed in constants expept in `1 << (len_a - 1)` which should be `1ull << (len_a - 1)`

Comment: Note: with `insertion: 1 deletion: 1 replacement: 2` a path without substitutions will be equal in cost to INDEL. So it could avoid all substitutions.

Comment: Before optimising, I would suggest to start with a naiv Needlemann-Wunch implementation. (yes, it is quadratic!) There exist optimisations to keep the path close to the diagonal (eg Hirchman)

Comment: @wildplasser I did not mention this in the question, but thats what I am currently using. The optimisations I use are: constant space (only one row stored), I remove the common prefix/suffix of the two strings in O(N) before calculating the distance and then for the Levenshtein calculation I use Ukkonen's optimization.

Comment: BTW: `uint64_t mask = 1ull << (len_a - 1);` are you sure you dont mean  `uint64_t mask = (1ull << len_a) - 1;` ? (which is an n-right bits mask instead of a single left bit mask)

Comment: yes thats intentional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement this using the algorithm described in [BitPAl: A Bit-Parallel, General Integer-Scoring Sequence Alignment Algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264639812_BitPAl_A_Bit-Parallel_General_Integer-Scoring_Sequence_Alignment_Algorithm).

```c
int weighted_levenshtein_bitpal(char* a, int len_a, char* b, int len_b)
{
  if (len_a > 64) {
    return -1;
  }

  uint64_t posbits[256] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < len_a; i++){
    posbits[(unsigned char)a[i]] |= 1ull << i;
  }

  uint64_t DHneg1 = ~0x0ull;
  uint64_t DHzero = 0;
  uint64_t DHpos1 = 0;

  //recursion
  for (int i = 0; i < len_b; ++i)
  {
    uint64_t Matches = posbits[(unsigned char)b[i]];
    //Complement Matches
    uint64_t NotMatches = ~Matches;

    //Finding the vertical values. //Find 1s
    uint64_t INITpos1s = DHneg1 & Matches;
    uint64_t DVpos1shift = (((INITpos1s + DHneg1) ^ DHneg1) ^ INITpos1s);

    //set RemainingDHneg1
    uint64_t RemainDHneg1 = DHneg1 ^ (DVpos1shift >> 1);
    //combine 1s and Matches
    uint64_t DVpos1shiftorMatch = DVpos1shift | Matches;

    //Find 0s
    uint64_t INITzeros = (DHzero & DVpos1shiftorMatch) ;
    uint64_t DVzeroshift = ((INITzeros << 1) + RemainDHneg1) ^ RemainDHneg1;

    //Find -1s
    uint64_t DVneg1shift = ~(DVpos1shift | DVzeroshift);
    DHzero &= NotMatches;
    //combine 1s and Matches
    uint64_t DHpos1orMatch = DHpos1| Matches;
    //Find 0s
    DHzero = (DVzeroshift & DHpos1orMatch) | (DVneg1shift & DHzero);
    //Find 1s
    DHpos1 = (DVneg1shift & DHpos1orMatch);
    //Find -1s
    DHneg1 = ~(DHzero | DHpos1);
  }
  //find scores in last row
  uint64_t add1 = DHzero;
  uint64_t add2 = DHpos1;

  int dist = len_b;

  for (int i = 0; i < len_a; i++)
  {
    uint64_t bitmask = 1ull << i;
    dist -= ((add1 & bitmask) >> i) * 1 + ((add2 & bitmask) >> i) * 2 - 1;
  }

  return dist;
}
```

The algorithm requires, that both strings only use characters below 256 (extended Ascii), and that string `a` has a `length < 65`. Support for characters over 256 (full utf32) can be added using a simple key value storage instead of the array:

```c
typedef struct {
  uint32_t key[128];
  uint64_t val[128];
} blockmap_entry;

void blockmap_insert(blockmap_entry* map, uint32_t ch, int pos) {
    uint8_t hash = ch % 128;
    uint32_t key = ch | 0x80000000U;

    while (map->key[hash] && map->key[hash] != key) {
      if (hash == 127) hash = 0;
      else hash++;
    }

    map->key[hash] = key;
    map->val[hash] |= 1 << pos;
}

uint64_t blockmap_get(blockmap_entry* map, uint32_t ch) {
    uint8_t hash = ch % 128;
    uint32_t key = ch | 0x80000000U;

    while (map->key[hash] && map->key[hash] != key) {
      if (hash == 127) hash = 0;
      else hash++;
    }

    return (map->key[hash] == key) ? map->val[hash] : 0;
}
```

The algorithm can then be implemented in the following way:

```c
int weighted_levenshtein_bitpal(uint32_t* a, int len_a, uint32_t* b, int len_b)
{
  if (len_a > 64) {
    return -1;
  }

  blockmap_entry posbits = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < len_a; i++){
    blockmap_insert(&posbits, a[i], i);
  }

  uint64_t DHneg1 = ~0x0ull;
  uint64_t DHzero = 0;
  uint64_t DHpos1 = 0;

  //recursion
  for (int i = 0; i < len_b; ++i)
  {
    uint64_t Matches = blockmap_get(&posbits, a[i]);
    //Complement Matches
    uint64_t NotMatches = ~Matches;

    //Finding the vertical values. //Find 1s
    uint64_t INITpos1s = DHneg1 & Matches;
    uint64_t DVpos1shift = (((INITpos1s + DHneg1) ^ DHneg1) ^ INITpos1s);

    //set RemainingDHneg1
    uint64_t RemainDHneg1 = DHneg1 ^ (DVpos1shift >> 1);
    //combine 1s and Matches
    uint64_t DVpos1shiftorMatch = DVpos1shift | Matches;

    //Find 0s
    uint64_t INITzeros = (DHzero & DVpos1shiftorMatch) ;
    uint64_t DVzeroshift = ((INITzeros << 1) + RemainDHneg1) ^ RemainDHneg1;

    //Find -1s
    uint64_t DVneg1shift = ~(DVpos1shift | DVzeroshift);
    DHzero &= NotMatches;
    //combine 1s and Matches
    uint64_t DHpos1orMatch = DHpos1| Matches;
    //Find 0s
    DHzero = (DVzeroshift & DHpos1orMatch) | (DVneg1shift & DHzero);
    //Find 1s
    DHpos1 = (DVneg1shift & DHpos1orMatch);
    //Find -1s
    DHneg1 = ~(DHzero | DHpos1);
  }
  //find scores in last row
  uint64_t add1 = DHzero;
  uint64_t add2 = DHpos1;

  int dist = len_b;

  for (int i = 0; i < len_a; i++)
  {
    uint64_t bitmask = 1ull << i;
    dist -= ((add1 & bitmask) >> i) * 1 + ((add2 & bitmask) >> i) * 2 - 1;
  }

  return dist;
}
```

It is possible to implement the same algorithm using multiple blocks for longer strings. A C++ implementation of this can be found [here](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz-cpp/blob/49fd71706e7959d4cca313b37abccbaa628bd4b6/rapidfuzz/details/string_metrics/weighted_levenshtein_impl.hpp#L105).