# string similarity of optimal alignment

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance, sequence-alignment

### Expected Behaviour of the algorithm

I have two strings `a` and `b`, with `a` being the shorter string. I would like to find the substring of `b`, that has the biggest similarity to `a`. The substring has to be of `len(a)`, or has to be placed at the end of `b`.
e.g. for the following two strings:

```
a = "aa"
b = "bbaba"
```

the possible substrings of b would be

```
"bb"
"ba"
"ab"
"ba"
"a"
""
```

The edit distance is defined as amount of Insertions and Deletion. Substitutions are not possible (Insertion + Deletion has to be used instead). The similarity between the two strings is calulated according to the following equation: `norm = 1 - distance / (len(a) + len(substring))`.
So the substrings above would provide the following results:

```
"bb" -> 2 DEL + 2 INS -> 1 - 4 / 4 = 0
"ba" -> 1 DEL + 1 INS -> 1 - 2 / 4 = 0.5
"ab" -> 1 DEL + 1 INS -> 1 - 2 / 4 = 0.5
"ba" -> 1 DEL + 1 INS -> 1 - 2 / 4 = 0.5
"a"  ->         1 INS -> 1 - 1 / 3 = 0.66
""   ->         2 INS -> 1 - 2 / 2 = 0
```

So the algorithm should return 0.66.

### Different implementations

A similar ratio is implemented by the Python library FuzzyWuzzy in the form of `fuzz.partial_ratio`. It calculates the ratio in two steps:

1. searches for matching subsequences in the longer sequence using difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks
2. calculates the ratio for substrings of len(shorter_string) starting at the matching subsequences and returns the maximum ratio

This is really slow, so it uses python-Levenshtein for this similarity calculation when it is available. This performs the same calculation based on the Levenshtein distance, which is faster. However in edge cases the calculated matching_blocks used for the ratio calculation is completely wrong (see [issue 16](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/issues/16)), which does not make it a suitable replacement, when the correctness is relevant.

### Current implementation

I currently use a C++ port of difflib in combination with a fast bitparallel implementation of the Levenshtein distance with the weights insertion=1, deletion=1 and substitution=2. The current implementation can be found here:

- extracting matching_blocks: [matching_blocks](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz-cpp/blob/16e94a9c04799e6f8c546bc239a4db348c26f584/rapidfuzz/details/matching_blocks.hpp#L154)
- calculating weighted Levenshtein: [weighted Levenshtein](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz-cpp/blob/16e94a9c04799e6f8c546bc239a4db348c26f584/rapidfuzz/details/string_metrics/weighted_levenshtein_impl.hpp#L386)
- combining them to calculate the end ratio: [partial_ratio](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz-cpp/blob/49fd71706e7959d4cca313b37abccbaa628bd4b6/rapidfuzz/fuzz_impl.hpp#L45)

### Question

Is there a faster algorithm to calculate this kind of similarity. Requirements are:

- only uses Replacement/Insertion (or gives substitutions the weight 2, which has a similar effect)
- allows a gap at the beginning of the longer string
- allows a gap at the end of the longer string, as long as the remaining substring does not become shorter, than the length of the shorter string.
- optimally it enforces, that the substring has a similar length (when it is not in the end), so it matches the behaviour of FuzzyWuzzy, but it would be fine when it allows longer subsequences to be matched aswell: e.g. for `aaba`:`aaa` this would mean, that it is allowed to use `aaba` as optimal subsequence instead of `aab`.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag since this is an algorithm request, not a code one.

Comment: Ah yes I mean the largest normalized edit distance

Comment: The most generic is Needlemann-Wunch, but that is O(N*M). Smitth-Waterman is faster, but does not compute the best alignment, nor the distance. Windowed/tiled variants (Hirchberg) for N-W exist. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65363769/905902 <<--Huh?

Comment: For the LCS, use Smith-Waterman